# Android fast image processing on Bitmap

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I found great Android image processing library "fastImageProcessing" here

https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing

Is there a way to use those filters on regular *Bitmap* and set it to *ImageView*?

Thank you.

Comment: class `ImageResourceInput ` provides `ImageResourceInput(GLSurfaceView view, Bitmap bitmap)` methods. But it seems doesn't support set `Bitmap` to `ImageView`. Why don't you use the view which the library provided?

Comment: I already have an app that uses ImageViews, and I need to use filters on images that I display to the user.